# Update records that can be retrieved by multiple joins in x++

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

So I have a complete x++ script that aims to update records based on the retrieved result set **made with select query with multiple joins and using crosscompany**

As I have been told, it is not a good idea to update records when there is crosscompany. Can you give expert advice on how to do it the best practice way considering my current script.

here is the script

```
static void UpdateSample(Args _args)
{

   InventTable  a;
   InventTableModule b;
   EcoResProduct c;
   EcoResProductCategory d;
   EcoResCategory e;
   EcoResCategoryHierarchy f;
   int i = 0;

    while select crossCompany  a
    exists join b where a.ItemId  == b.ItemId  
    exists  join c where a.Product  == c.RecId
    exists join d where c.RecId  == d.Product
    exists join e where d.Category  == e.RecId
    exists join f where d.CategoryHierarchy  == f.RecId
    && a.dataAreaId == 'DAT' && b.ModuleType  == 2
    && b.LineDisc  == ''
    && f.name == 'EXAMPLE'
    &&(e.name == 'sample1' || e.name == 'sample2' || e.name == 'sample3')

       {
        if (a)
             {
              i = i + 1;
              ttsBegin;
              b.LineDisc= 'something';
              b.update();
              ttscommit;
             }
        }
     info(strfmt("total record/s updated : %1",i));
}
```

When I run above,  am having this error

***"Cannot edit a record in Inventory module parameters (InventTableModule).
The record has never been selected."***

As solution, based on this link [How to Update/Insert/Delete CrossCompany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353085/how-to-update-insert-delete-crosscompany), i tried following the same, this is the modified script

```
static void UpdateSample(Args _args)
{
   InventTable  a;
   InventTableModule b;
   EcoResProduct c;
   EcoResProductCategory d;
   EcoResCategory e;
   EcoResCategoryHierarchy f;
   int i = 0;

    while select crossCompany  a
    exists join b where a.ItemId  == b.ItemId  
    exists  join c where a.Product  == c.RecId
    exists join d where c.RecId  == d.Product
    exists join e where d.Category  == e.RecId
    exists join f where d.CategoryHierarchy  == f.RecId
    && a.dataAreaId == 'DAT' && b.ModuleType  == 2
    && b.LineDisc  == ''
    && f.name == 'EXAMPLE'
    &&(e.name == 'sample1' || e.name == 'sample2' || e.name == 'sample3')

       {
       if (a)
             {
              i = i + 1;
              b.LineDisc= 'something'; 
              b.selectForUpdate(true);
              ttsBegin;
              b.update();
              ttsCommit;
             }
        }
     info(strfmt("total record/s updated : %1",i));
}
```

But I am having SYNTAX ERROR on this line

```
 b.selectForUpdate(true);
```

I am new to x++, hope i can get expert advice about the best practice in doing this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your try/catch does nothing usefull, delete it.

Comment: Your code does not compile, inv was not defined nor found within loop.

Comment: Please use source code which compiles against standard application.

Comment: Take a look at [Cross-Company Data Modification Using X++](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dynamicsax-2012/developer/cross-company-data-modification-using-x)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to Update/Insert/Delete CrossCompany](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35353085/how-to-update-insert-delete-crosscompany)

Comment: Sorry, Yes, i already edited the variable consistencies, removed try catch.. @JanB.Kjeldsen

Comment: hi @FH-Inway as per the second link, do you mean removing the FORUPDATE on the top and replace it Table.selectForUpdate(true) in the inner body part ? for the result set with crosscompany be updated?

Comment: it's not that the same thought, as mine used multiple joins table

Comment: hi @JanB.Kjeldsen any feedback?

Comment: You have not supplied a script on real tables. Take a look on https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899654/4509.

Comment: oh you want me to use the real table names?

Comment: @JanB.Kjeldsen , so i edited the script with the actual script i am working on right now... hope to get positive feedback on this

Comment: You really need to use the tab key!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

First off, do not try to do update cross company, it is bound to fail.
Make the update work in current company, then apply the script to other relevant companies.

Fixed a few things:

- Trying to update a record found with exists join will not work, hence your error.
- Testing on record found is redundant, the loop will not be entered if none is found
- Use a large transaction

Also put the update in an inner function, this will make it easy to update in more than one company. See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11899654/4509) on how to do in all companies.

```
static void UpdateSample(Args _args)
{
    void doIt()
    {
        InventTable  a;
        InventTableModule b;
        EcoResProduct c;
        EcoResProductCategory d;
        EcoResCategory e;
        EcoResCategoryHierarchy f;
        int i;
        ttsBegin;
        while select a
            join forUpdate b where a.ItemId  == b.ItemId  
            exists join c where a.Product  == c.RecId
            exists join d where c.RecId  == d.Product
            exists join e where d.Category  == e.RecId
            exists join f where d.CategoryHierarchy  == f.RecId
            && b.ModuleType  == 2
            && b.LineDisc  == ''
            && f.name == 'EXAMPLE'
            &&(e.name == 'sample1' || e.name == 'sample2' || e.name == 'sample3')
        {
            ++i;
            b.LineDisc= 'something'; 
            b.update();
        }
        ttsCommit;
        info(strfmt("total record/s updated : %1", i));
    }
    changecompany ('XXX')
        doIt();
}
```

Comment: so the fltering to specify what dataareaid / location it is is removed..

Comment: Never do that, use changecompany (or apply in current company).

Comment: so the line changeCompany, the dataareaid / location specification should be there in ('xxx')  right? instead of specifying in the inner query

Comment: A good guess .... and my guess is you really only want to update in a single company. You must learn how to change company using the user interface.

Comment: Yes, just to give a background, there were expected errors in value in linedisc of these item masters in a SPECIFIC LOCATION only due to incorrect setup prior to releasing of items. so need to FIND FIRST this items, and can only be found by using the joins in select query.

Comment: I plan to do it in SQL but i believe doing in in x++ scripting is better

Comment: another method i thought of is one by one update in x++ by referencing to recid in inventtablemodule.. after i retrieve them from sql query

Comment: This is nuts, fix your query.

Comment: For others searching - see this answer for a simple example https://stackoverflow.com/a/35354290/1179573